# Exibir conteúdo de variável em Javascript que possui aspas

Tags: javascript

Possuo uma aplicação que lê em ajax um banco de dados MySQL, o qual nele está gravado um conteúdo normal (sem ser escapado) com várias palavras entre aspas duplas, simples ou só com uma aspas simples.

Esse conteúdo vai pra uma variável, ex:

```
conteúdo que está no banco de dados...= Quantos litros d'água está "sujo"

wVar = conteúdo acima
```

Tenho que exibir isso concatenando com outro texto, tipo:

```
alert("texto = "+wVar);
```

é como eu estivesse querendo exibir `"texto = "+"Quantos litros d'água está "sujo""`

Ai dá erro, logicamente por causa das aspas duplas da palavra "sujo" não estar escapada.

Como posso exibir estas frases de forma correta sem saber exatamente o conteúdo que será carregado do banco de dados na variável?

OBS: Na exibição a palavra "sujo" precisar ser exibida com as aspas duplas, pois faz parte do conteúdo correto do texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode colocar o retorno do banco direto na variável JavaScript entre aspas (duplas ou simples) e usar o método **[addslashes](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addslashes.php)** do PHP que irá escapar as aspas necessárias:

```
<script>
wVar = "<?=addslashes($texto_vindo_do_banco?>";
alert("texto = "+wVar);
</script>
```

Comment: $texto_vindo_do_banco = ????

Comment: Sim, de uma query.

Comment: sim, eu sei, como iniciar essa variável `$texto_vindo_do_banco = ?????`

Comment: Poderia ser `$row['texto'])`, de `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar aspas invertidas, exemplo:

```
alert(`Início do texto, agora a variável:${wVar}`)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Answer (score 0):

Dê um replace no conteúdo que vem do banco escapando as aspas duplas

```js
var wVar = "Quantos litros d'água está \"sujo\"";

alert("texto = "+wVar);
```